# Question regarding meaning of an unspecified term

Tags: terminology

Hi I was trying to solve questions from this year's Sharygin Maths Olympiad and I came across a problem in which it was written that the three bisectors of the triangle meet at X.
Now is the question trying to say bisectors as in angle bisectors or medians?
Just for context, this is a paper from Russia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on usage, but I would think "bisectors" were for angles.